# Make the task bar visible at all times

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, modern-ui

With the recent Windows 8.1 update we are able to run "Metro" apps inside the desktop view, but when so, the task bar fades away (hides) and it is very irritating to click twice and some times more to just make the task visible again.

Is there any way to force the task bar to be visible regardless if I'm using desktop applications or "Metro" application inside the desktop view?

Comment: No one has figured this out yet?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know any way to keep the taskbar visible all the time. But you can use a quick shortcuts to get this back.

Start + D = To view desktop.
Alt+ Tab = To switch between apps quickly
Alt+F4 = To close an app

Hope this may help.

Also check whether you taskbar auto hide option is not enabled. Right click on taskbar > Properties > Uncheck auto hide taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

There's a link here that might help: [Removing Windows 8.1’s universal desktop taskbar](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2145342/how-to-prevent-windows-8-1s-desktop-taskbar-from-showing-in-metro-apps.html) and i think the screenshot says it all (which i unfortunately can't post yet due to rep) - so you'll have to make dow tih the link: [screenshot](http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/04/windows-8.1-taskbar-properties-100262407-medium.png)

To quote @BradChacos from that site:

> Right-click in an empty space on the taskbar, then open the Taskbar tab. See the “Show Windows Store apps on the taskbar” option? It doesn’t mention the taskbar’s universal properties whatsoever, but it’s what you’re looking for. Uncheck it, then click OK.

Check, instead of uncheck and you should be done.

I'll be testing this when i have access to my windows 8 machine, but for now this is all i have.

Comment: That does what I already have done. The issue is, the Task bar auto hides when a Metro app opens. I don't want it to auto hide.

Comment: That's too bad. I'll try some more when i get to a W8.1 machine.

Comment: Didn't find a solution either. Googled for it, but no can do. Only using the mouse, but without clicks i have to add.. If feels like a mouse-swipe, but it's no answer to your question how to force the task bar visibility.

Comment: Appreciate your effort, will update this post once I find a solution or some one else does.

Comment: Looks like this has been resolved in "Windows 9", we have to wait for that update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "StartIsBack" and I have to say that its a whole better experience than using stock MS WIN8 taskbar ..

OTHER OPTION
would be to install Modern MIX from Stardock's website and give it a try.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Super User!  We expect answers to be more comprehensive here.  Please read [this thread](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511) on how to recommend software in an answer.  Could you edit your answer and include where these programs can be found, how they can be installed, and how they can be used for what the OP needs?

Answer (score -1):

just found the answer to your problem

right click anywhere on the taskbar ---> PROPERTIES ---> uncheck "auto-hide the taskbar "

Comment: This doesn't change behavior for the Start screen.